# Is there any alternative service like in Amazon Appstream2.0 and Amazon Workspace in Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to search for an alternative of Amazon Appstream2.0 and Amazon Workspace(DAAS) in Azure. Those services in Amazon really provide the solution for remote purpose but I am really handy with azure. If I can get the solution in azure I can move to azure for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no native service similar to Amazon Appstream2.0 in Azure.

[Cloud compare](http://comparecloud.in/) also doesn't show any alternatives:

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

As @Pradyumna mentioned substitute of Amazon Workspace in Azure Cloud could be [Window Virtual Desktop(WVD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/overview).

> Here's what you can do when you run Windows Virtual Desktop on Azure:
>
> - Set up a multi-session Windows 10 deployment that delivers a full    Windows 10 with scalability
> - Virtualize Microsoft 365 Apps for    enterprise and optimize it to run in multi-user virtual scenarios
> - Provide Windows 7 virtual desktops with free Extended Security    Updates
> - Bring your existing Remote Desktop Services (RDS) and Windows    Server desktops and apps to any computer
> - Virtualize both desktops and    apps Manage
> - Windows 10, Windows Server, and Windows 7 desktops and    apps with a unified management experience

Comment: Hi, I found one substitute for Amazon Workspace in azure that is Window Virtual Desktop(WVD) which provide same solution as Desktop virtualization like Workspace. Go through the link "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/overview"

Comment: Great! I edited the answer with your research, please mark it as an answer for other users.